# Laravel - SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation

Tags: html, mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin, laravel-5.3

i know  this question has already asked before ,but i can't fix it
I'm new at php and I used Laravel 5 and Bitnami Wamp Stack as my server

[this is my error page when i try to insert new data to my Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecusE.jpg)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8eaE.jpg

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have a type in the form. Change this:

```
pruduct_id
```

to this:

```
product_id
```